# Compute limit using Taylor's expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Using Taylor’s expansion, prove that the following limit exists and compute it.

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac {x^2}{\frac {1}{1-x} - e^x}\right)$$

In this if I am using the taylor series expansion of $e^x$ then denominator has some value as $$ 1 + (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots) + x (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots) $$

I am not getting how to proceed further with this.

Comment: Your expanded denominator doesn't seem right. Check your expansion of $e^x$ (and why do you add a 1 in front?)

Comment: @Nigel, $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}$$

Comment: I have seen this problem a lot of time, and i was wondering if there's a method to solve this without L'hopitals and taylor series?

Comment: This is the same as this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266342/taylor-expansion-to-prove-that-a-limit-doesnt-exist/1266353#1266353

I think this question should be closed.

Comment: @HasanSaad Sorry I looked on that problem. But I was facing few thing which I stated and hence now my doubts are clear

Comment: @Kittu May I ask where you got this question from? 

Funnily enough, my professor gave me the exact same question, a few days ago has a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First we have

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} - e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \Big(1 - \frac{1}{n!}\Big) = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{5x^3}{6} + O (x^4) $$

Then

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{5x^3}{6} + O (x^4)}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: yeah I got it. Limit will be equal to 2

Comment: But do i need to prove that this limit exists before solving ?

Comment: That's it! Good job.

Comment: As long as $|x| < 1$ your Taylor series converges to the functions in question. That is, you're looking at the limit in a certain neighbourhood around $0$, which allows you to evaluate both sided limits.

Comment: @Kittu Looking at your profile, you should take a look at this [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers). If any of the answers here were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{1-x}-e^x&=1+x+x^2+o(x^2)-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\\&=\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\end{align}$$
This means the limit we are looking for is $2$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do. Note
$$ (1-x)e^x=(1-x)(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2))=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)$$
and hence
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac {x^2}{\frac {1}{1-x} - e^x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(1-x)}{1-(1-x)e^x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(1-x)}{\frac{1}{2}x^2+o(x^2)}=2.$$